# How to use deepnet for classification in R

Tags: r, classification

When i use code from example:

```
library(deepnet)
Var1 <- c(rnorm(50, 1, 0.5), rnorm(50, -0.6, 0.2))
Var2 <- c(rnorm(50, -0.8, 0.2), rnorm(50, 2, 1))
x <- matrix(c(Var1, Var2), nrow = 100, ncol = 2)
y <- c(rep(1, 50), rep(0, 50))
nn <- dbn.dnn.train(x, y, hidden = c(5))
```

it works. But when i use this code:

```
Var1 <- c(rnorm(50, 1, 0.5), rnorm(50, -0.6, 0.2))
Var2 <- c(rnorm(50, -0.8, 0.2), rnorm(50, 2, 1))
x <- matrix(c(Var1, Var2), nrow = 100, ncol = 2)
**y <- c(rep("1", 50), rep("0", 50))**
nn <- dbn.dnn.train(x, y, hidden = c(5))
```

i receive error:

> Error in batch_y - nn$post[[i]] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

How can i use deepnet package for classification problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
y1 <- c(rep("1", 50), rep("0", 50))
```

lead you to character vector which is not acceptable by the package. so that you get error

```
class(y)
#[1] "character"
```

The right y should be numeric as follows

```
y <- c(rep(1, 50), rep(0, 50))
class(y)
#[1] "numeric"
```

if you see inside your y , you can find that you have 1 or 0 which is a binary values for classification

```
> table(y)
#y
# 0  1 
#50 50
```

If you want to train as it is mentioned in the manual, you can do the following to train and predict a test set

```
Var1 <- c(rnorm(50, 1, 0.5), rnorm(50, -0.6, 0.2))
Var2 <- c(rnorm(50, -0.8, 0.2), rnorm(50, 2, 1))
x <- matrix(c(Var1, Var2), nrow = 100, ncol = 2)
y <- c(rep(1, 50), rep(0, 50))
```

If you now look at your x and y by **str** just simply write *str(x)* or *str(y)* you can see that they are numeric (to make sure, you can check them by class(x) and class(y).

After having your X and y , then you can build your model

```
dnn <- dbn.dnn.train(x, y, hidden = c(5, 5))
```

If you have a test set to predict, then you can predict it using for example as is mentioned in the manual

```
test_Var1 <- c(rnorm(50, 1, 0.5), rnorm(50, -0.6, 0.2))
test_Var2 <- c(rnorm(50, -0.8, 0.2), rnorm(50, 2, 1))
test_x <- matrix(c(test_Var1, test_Var2), nrow = 100, ncol = 2)
nn.test(dnn, test_x, y)

#[1] 0.25
```

Again your test_x must be numeric. If your problem is that you have the values as character, then you can convert it to numeric by `mydata<- as.numeric()`

Comment: when i use numeric, i get regression model, not classification. As result, after predict i got numeric results, not classes ID.

Comment: @Osm classification and regression are very very similar. you should round your output prediction if you want to get exact binary values. for example use **round(x)** then you will have those that are close to zero , as zero and those that are close to 1 as one. moreover if the model did not predict it correctly you might have 2 or 3 etc which it can be very useful for confusion matrix you are going to calculate